# Render multiple models in OpenGL with a single draw call

Tags: opengl, 3d, shader

I built a 2D graphical engine, and I created a batching system for it, so, if I have 1000 sprites with the same texture, I can draw them with one single call to openGl.

This is achieved by putting in a single vbo vertex array all the vertices of all the sprites with the same texture.

Instead of "print these vertices, print these vertices, print these vertices", I do "put all the vertices toghether, print", just to be very clear.
Easy enough, but now I'm trying to achieve the same thing in 3D, and I'm having a big problem.

The problem is that I'm using a Model View Projection matrix to place and render my models, which is the common approach to render a model in 3D space.

For each model on screen, I need to pass the MVP matrix to the shader, so that I can use it to transform each vertex to the correct position.

If I would do the transformation outside the shader, it would be executed by the cpu, which I not a good idea, for obvious reasons.

But the problem lies there. I need to pass the matrix to the shader, but for each model the matrix is different.

So I cannot do the same I did with 2d sprites, because changing a shader uniform requires a draw every time.

I hope I've been clear, maybe you have a good idea I didn't have or you already had the same problem. I know for a fact that there is a solution somewhere, because in engine like Unity, you can use the same shader for multiple models, and get away with one draw call

Answer (score 9):

There exists a feature exactly like what you're looking for, and it's called **instancing**. With instancing, you store `n` matrices (or whatever else you need) in a Uniform Buffer and call `glDrawElementsInstanced` to draw `n` copies. In the shader, you get an extra input `gl_InstanceID`, with which you index into the Uniform Buffer to fetch the matrix you need for that particular instance.

You can read more about instancing here: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Instancing

Comment: Awesome answer! I tought about implementing something similiar by myself, but i didn't really know how, this is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on whether the vertex data for each item is identical or not. If it is, you can use instancing as in @orost's answer, using `glDrawElementsInstanced`, and `gl_InstanceID` within the vertex shader, and that method should be preferred.

However, if each 3D model requires different vertex data (which is frequently the case), you can still render them using a single draw call. To do this, you would add another stream into your vertex data with `glVertexAttribPointer` (and `glEnableVertexAttribArray`). This extra stream would contain the index of the matrix within the uniform buffer that vertex should use when rendering - so each mesh within the VBO would have an identical index in the extra stream. The uniform buffer contains the same data as in the instancing setup.

Note this method may require some extra CPU processing, if you need to redo the batching - for example, an object within a batch should not be rendered anymore. If this process is required frequently, it should be determined whether batching items is actually beneficial or not.

Comment: Best answer i had so far, it really helped me understand how to approach it...Maybe i'll try to write a system that automatically choose instancing or this method...I can save along with the meshes the number of its vertices.
Then, each time i add a mesh to the system, if the number is the same of the mesh before, i keep a bool isInstance = true, but as soon as i get a different number of vertices, i set it to false.
At the end of the frame i render using one or the other method, depending on the bool value

Comment: Seems reasonable to you?

Comment: @user3578051 it's not only the number of vertices that's important, it's the actual content. Instancing basically just draws the same mesh multiple times. Presumably you'd vary the uniform data between instances. In this method, the contents of the vertex buffer data can be completely different between instances. A system that can handle both (and prefer instancing) would probably be the correct approach, except if say your batches change every frame.

Comment: mmm....no wait, i'll tell you what i understood and you tell me what i got wrong.

The idea is to put all the vertices in one vbo (each vertex contains position, color, normal and whatever else).

Let's say  i add a cube, and then a huge mesh (1000 verteices total).
My vbo will have 36+1000 vertices.
Then i have a uniform buffer containing the MVP matrices, which are two, in this case.

What i understood is to have a buffer of  length 1036, where the first 36 are pointers to the first matrix, the other pointers to the second.

Is that correct?

Comment: If that is correct my idea would be:

1) I'll give each mesh an identifier (because you said that the number of vertices alone is not sufficient)
2) Every time i add to the batch, i put the model in the batch with it's own texture
3)If the id is different though, i'll switch to not-instancing
4)at the end of the frame i render in the two ways depending on the method i need to use.

Is that fine?

Comment: I think that sounds like it would work. I just wanted to make clear that you could have two meshes that are different, but have the same number of vertices.

Comment: Ok perfect, yes i knew the fact by i tought that with instancing you should also pass a vbo with all the vertex for all the matrices, then specify how to "cut it" to the gpu.

For example for ten cubes, pass a 360 vertices vbo, and tell the gpu to take 36 vertices at a time.

In that case i tought that even same-numbered meshes would work, but probably instancing just require a single mesh as a parameter and a N number to do the work, i've not tried yet, so i didn't know.

Thanks for the answers, now my ideas are way more clear

Comment: News: I implemented the batch system, and the instancing.
I would like to add your method to it, to handle different models, so i made the extra stream, passed the indexes, but how can i use them in the shader? I get a matrix from the instancing stream, and an index from yours...but i cannot use that index to get a matrix from the vbo, cause in the vertex shader i only have a single matrix...i hope i've been clear...

Comment: Your matrices should be set as uniforms in the shader, not as a VBO.

Answer (score 0):

Besides instancing and adding another vertex attribute as some object ID, I'd like to also mention another strategy (which requires modern OpenGL, though):

The extension [ARB_multi_draw_indirect](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/multi_draw_indirect.txt) (in core since GL 4.3) adds *indirect* drawing commands. These commands do source their parameters (number of vertices, starting index and so on) directly from another buffer object. With these functions, many different objects can be drawn with a single draw call.

However, as you still want some per-object state like transformation matrices, that feature is not enough. But in combination with [ARB_shader_draw_parameters](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shader_draw_parameters.txt) (not in core GL yet), you get the `gl_DrawID` parameter, which will be incremented by one for each single object in one mult draw indirect call. That way, you can index into some UBO, or TBO, or SSBO (or whatever) where you store per-object data.